# React-JS, function output not being render in JSX

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx, rendering

my goal is to display data from an API:

```
async function getNFTData(){
const response = await fetch(`https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/items/${chain}:${address}:${Id}`)
const data = await response.json()
setNfts(data.items)
console.log(data)
console.log(data.meta.name)
return(
  <h>{data.meta.name}</h>
)}
```

And I can see the data perfectly in the **console.log**, but I can't get it to render in **JXS**.
I have used the code:

```
{this.getNFTData}

{this.getNFTData()}

{this.getNFTData.bind(this)}
```

And all of these have returned a same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getNFTData')
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `getNFTData()` instead of `this.getNFTData()`? The `this` keyword is pretty janky in JS and from the little code you provided it doesn't look right.

Comment: @kil if I use **getNFTData()** it starts calling the function, and in the api call I need the required data to make the call, since the data is not available it starts giving errors and doesn't renders the UI.

Comment: @kil I think the problem lies in rendering an async function. I'm looking into it.

Comment: @kil I got it. Ended up using a **useState snippet**, setting the **(data.meta.name)** in set state and then passing it to original state in **JSX**

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice the function was async, my bad. You might want to look into [`react-query`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-query) to handle this kind of stuff.